# Get maximum from absolute values returning signed value

Tags: vb.net, search, collections, max, min

Supposing I have a class

```
Public Class Foo
    Property fooProp1 as Single
    Property fooProp2 as Single
    Property fooProp3 as Single
End Class
```

to find the absolut maximum of a property (which contains positive or negative values) in a `Collection(Of Foo)` I can do:

```
Collection.Max(Function(x As foo) Math.Abs(x.fooProp1))
```

and it returns the greater absolute value WITHOUT sign.

The question is how can I do to get the number WITH sign?

Thanks in advance.
RG

Answer (score 0):

Math.Abs will **always return an unsigned value** (the actual meaning of Absolute).

The get the value of a property you need only to READ it.

To get a MAX or MIN, you MUST compare values, like this:

```
        dim x as integer = foo.property
        dim y as integer = last_foo_property (or anything else)

        Minimum = Math.Min(x,y)
        Maximum = Math.Max(x,y)
```

But, if are trying to get the lower and upper values of a collection, you may utilize:

```
      MaxValue = Collection.Find(Collection, Function(Z) (Z > BiggerValue))

      MinValue = Collection.Find(Collection, Function(Z) (Z < LowerValue))
```

where these values are gotten before the call.

Another way is to make a SORT and get the first and the last values...

Comment: Thanks for the reply but this dont answer my question...I have an ObservableCollection(Of Foo) and the class foo has 4 props. I need the absolute Maximum of one of the props of all foo-items in the collection. I could create for ex. a function, iterate and compare, having at the end of the operation my desired value signed. Or getting the max and min values, then comparing their absolute values and returning the biggest one, but I was looking for a more elegant solution, like in my example an inline delegate

Answer (score 0):

```
Collection.Select(Function(x) a.fooProp1).Aggregate(Function(a, b) 
                                                    If(Math.Abs(a) > Math.Abs(b), a, b))
```